# Information Extraction form LinkedIn

Tags: python, data-extraction

I have a company name and a designation (eg: CEO Google). I want to get information like name, email, etc from the LinkedIn profile using search API's of the respective person. I have tried using Google Search API but it has limitations for the number of searches.Is there any other alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you want to do/achieve. 
However, I'll drop the link to a repo of mine where you can have a look at how I extract, for educational purposes, information from job offers and/or profile pages.
[Here](https://github.com/fabriziomiano/linkedin-scraper) is the link.

Hope it helps